# Show that $\psi$ is a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

How would one show that $$T: \mathcal D \to\mathbb R $$
$$\psi\to \newcommand\inner[2]{\langle #1,#2 \rangle}\inner{T}{\psi} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \psi (n) $$ is a distribution.

I know that $T$ is a distribution in for every compact set $K$, one can find constants $c$ and  $j$ such that $\|\inner {T}\psi{}\|\leq c ×sup_{x\in K,|\alpha|\leq j} |D^\alpha \psi|$

Comment: Once $K=[a,b]$ is fixed, forall $\psi \in C^\infty_c(K)$ then $\langle T, \psi \rangle = \sum_{n \in [a,b]} \psi(n)$ so $|\langle T, \psi \rangle| \le $..

Comment: Thanks @reuns I've  figured  it